# PHP insert into MYSQL form

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am having problems with my first php project which i am doing to teach my self a bit about it.So i made a form here is code:

**vpis.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Php-Web Page - Input</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="glava">
            <center>Php Spletna Stran</center>
            <hr/>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <center>
                <a href="index.php">NAZAJ</a>
                <a href="bris.html">BRISANJE</a>
            </center>
            <hr/>
        </div>

        <div id ="vsebina">

            <div div="vpisigr">
                <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                    Vpisovanje igralca<br/>
                    ID:<input type="text" name="pid" size="20"/><br/>
                    Ime:<input type="text" name="pime" size="20"/><br/>
                    Priimek:<input type="text" name="ppriimek" size="20"/><br/>
                    Starost:<input type="text" name="pstarost" size="20"/><br/>
                    Velikost:<input type="text" name="pvelikost" size="20"/><br/>
                    Polozaj:<input type="text" name="ppolozaj" size="20"/><br/>
                    ID Kluba:<input type="text" name="ppid" size="20"/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Shrani"/>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr/>

        <div id="footer">
            <center>Vse pravice pridržane </center>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

So here i require from user to enter all data to insert into database. Here is screenshoot of database:

[image: Database image]

and here is **insert.php** which is called as form action

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("php", $con);
//hmmmm ne dela
$sql="INSERT INTO Igralec (iID, iIME, iPRIIMEK, iSTAROST, iVELIKOST, iPOLOZAJ, ID)
VALUES ('$_POST[pid]', '$_POST[pime]', '$_POST[ppriimek]', '$_POST[pstarost]', '$_POST[pvelikost]', '$_POST[ppolozaj]', '$_POST[ppid]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

//die(print_r($_POST));
echo "Dodana je ena nova vrstica";


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The problem is thath evry time i submit data, it writes false data into database all in format like
0--0-0-00 or simmilar to thath. But in array before is written it contains correct data but somehow it writes in database false data.

Comment: There is lots of SQL injection possibilities in your code. You should escape your params.

If you echo $sql, what does that show?

Comment: Sure i belive thath there are a lot of possibilities but i need this only for learning purposes, will do on security later :)

Comment: If you echo $sql, what does that show? I think you may need to encase your params in {curly brackets} if you're embedding them into the statement like that.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Best to start off with best practices eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your $sql variable to this:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO Igralec (iID, iIME, iPRIIMEK, iSTAROST, iVELIKOST, iPOLOZAJ, ID)
VALUES ('".$_POST[pid]."', '".$_POST[pime]."', '".$_POST[ppriimek]."', '".$_POST[pstarost]."', '".$_POST[pvelikost]."', '".$_POST[ppolozaj]."', '".$_POST[ppid]."')";
```

Comment: Oh lol thath works so syntax was wrong :S

Answer (score 3):

Try this as your query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Igralec (iID, iIME, iPRIIMEK, iSTAROST, iVELIKOST, iPOLOZAJ, ID)
VALUES ('".$_POST['pid']."', '".$_POST['pime']."', '".$_POST['ppriimek']."', '".$_POST['pstarost']."', '".$_POST['pvelikost']."', '".$_POST['ppolozaj']."', '".$_POST['ppid']."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with associative arrays, the keys are like strings.

```
$_POST['ppolozaj']
```

You should put your variables in curly braces to allow easier parsing.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Igralec (iID, iIME, iPRIIMEK, iSTAROST, iVELIKOST, iPOLOZAJ, ID)
VALUES ('{$_POST['pid']}', '{$_POST['pime']}', '{$_POST['ppriimek']}', '{$_POST['pstarost']}', '{$_POST['pvelikost']}', '{$_POST['ppolozaj']}', '{$_POST['ppid']}')";
```

I understand this is for learning purposes.  It is best to learn the best practices now vice later.  Two things to help with security in this statement are the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function as well as [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.